# how to create missing value rate (10%,20% etc.) from complete dataset in python

Tags: python, missing-data

Can anyone tell me to how to create datasets with missing values with different percentage like(10%,20%) from original datasets in python.

Comment: Please tell what have you tried so far and also give an example of a data-set you are working on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 percent

```
import random
a_list = range(25)
print(random.sample(a_list,len(a_list) - len(a_list)//10))
```

it doesnt preserve order however

if you need to preserve order

```
import random
a_list = range(25)
indexes = sorted(random.sample(range(len(a_list)),len(a_list)//10),reverse=True)
for i in indexes:
    del a_list[i]
print(a_list)
```

is one way.

if you want a 10% chance of dropping any element

```
new_list = [x for x in a_list if random.random()>0.1]
```